# Haskell: implementing Read for a custom dynamic value type

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, variant-type

I'm using Haskell to interpret a dynamically-typed language. I have a sum type called `Value` which can represent some basic objects:

```hs
data Value
  = Integer Integer
  | Float Double
  | Char Char
  | List [Value]
  deriving Show
```

(For now I'm not adding a special case for strings - they'll just be lists of characters.)

I have instantiated `Read` for it, so that I can parse string inputs into `Value`s as though they're normal Haskell values.

While for this demo I just derived `Show` using the default implementation, I had to define `Read` manually, because I don't want the input to need the data constructors prefixed before every element. (I would have to write input as `Integer 43` instead of just `43`, for example)

I implement `readsPrec` (which seems a needlessly complex method to have as the minimal typeclass implementation, but it's what Haskell requires...) in terms of Haskell's default implementations for the underlying data types.

`readsPrec` takes a precedence value, which I just pass on to the `readsPrec` of other types; it returns a list of possible parses as tuples of `(value, restOfString)`.

The basic algorithm I use is to attempt to parse the input into each type, and choose the first result from each. Unfortunately there's quite a lot of plumbing required to deal with the list of tuples produced by `readsPrec`.

```hs
instance Read Value where
  readsPrec precedence s =
    -- `justs` stops the parsing once all of the read attempts are failing
    justs $ map (foldl orElse Nothing) $ transpose attempts
      where
        -- try to parse the input into each of these types, one at a time
        attempts = [u Integer, u Float, u Char, u List]
        u constructor = maybes [(constructor val, rest) | (val, rest) <- readsPrec precedence s]
```

This implementation also uses a couple of utility functions:

```hs
-- | Create an infinite list of Maybes, where the elements in the input
-- | are `Just`s, and everything after that is a `Nothing`
maybes xs = map Just xs ++ repeat Nothing

-- | Collect the values of all Justs at the start of a list
justs (Just x : xs) = x : justs xs
justs _             = []
```

I want to know if my code, especially the plumbing around `readsPrec`, can be made more idiomatic, perhaps using some more builtin functions. Maybe the whole algorithm can be simplified.

I also don't like the fact I'm using a constant-sized list for the attempts. I'd like to be able to just use a tuple, but if I ever wanted to add more data types, I'd have to change things like `unzip4` to `unzip5`, because I can't write it polymorphically over tuple size. (where `unzip` would be used for tuples, in place of `transpose` for lists)

I'm not really interested in whether the minutiae of my syntax style are "correct".

[Here is an online demo of my code](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVPBjtMwED1wy1e8A1JTbcoBOKCK1R4WkIoAIZC4VNXGbaZNwLEje9ztSnwGNy57WXHkf_gaxnZaeiGHJJ7xzLz3_PzzV6v8N9L6_v4h8Hb24s-jH10_WMd4pVg9edd5RslOGT9YT9OiaCSML0oHKoBLLAzTjtzxK7HveKOtknob1ppS4LpVLr3SKvVcphYrCTTkun1ndvjc2tui6IxnZTaET6SaPAi3LbnYyUnIf3S0wSAvaiju84JCcsDX4NnjMXo1oNxa3WhY91p7wgfLrUyYSvJEBYqZ-oF9qsVpRn6OSem9DEdyFULmFn8infiNbFanuoCNFQIubNg6Ke7V3Zo8luV5eK90JVw8T0WN8mz1cvYfiquimM2wmPTwwdGRVudlOUQyDdhiLREDqdWhoQrrwFhgF8h7GMtXVyLttjs4PEWdG9RF-VY0w2F6iuBGQOdgMaqGf8mDJA8JipypIGVR0SC2NZ3863iwdov3iXSVJQW3BNLUkxE5BWBcd2YInPso2VLHibVUKNOA9uTu8mS1ZbEWt-Im4apQj5DqYtT14JPGwwjZ4-JCFBwE2fHMj2it1rThNHwfPeUjUKV1qpTeOSXWc4mCSmSKbKlRJcxlwjRKIH85c_DjlhucP2KafGIN9RbBk-AV5pdorDglkY9nvSO-tmItk0w4uM6wOLSMFhg3zef5Bkzz5Rzv6P3v5bPnFSZqUmG5XK1WOfwX).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm is fine. Your `Read` instance, however, isn't. There are semi-written laws, namely that for any type `A` that instanciates both `Show` and `Read` the following laws hold:

- if I `read` a value and then `show` it again, I will end up with the same string (except for whitespace changes):

  ```
  srIdentity :: (Read a, Show a) => a -> String -> String
  srIdentity x s = show (read s `asTypeOf` x)
  ```
- if I `show` a value and then `read` it again, I get the same value back:

  ```
  rsIdentity :: (Show a, Read a) => a -> a
  rsIdentity = read . show
  ```
- the process must be repeatable for both variants

  ```
  srsrIdentity :: (Show a, Read a) => a -> String -> String
  srsrIdentity x = srIdentity x . srIdentity x

  rsrsIdentity :: (Show a, Read a) => a -> a
  rsrsIdentity = rsIdentity . rsIdentity
  ```

Your `Read` instance does not hold any of those laws. What you *really* want is a regular function

```
parseString :: String -> Value
```

Usually, you would use one of the [(many) parsing libraries](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/#cat:Parsing) for this, like `attoparsec` or `parsec`. Many of those parsers are also `Monad` or even `MonadPlus` (or `Alternative`), so you end up with something along

```
valueP :: Parser Value
valueP =  integerP
      <|> floatP
      <|> charP
      <|> many valueP
```

> I'd like to be able to just use a tuple, but if I ever wanted to add more data types

Adding a new type would then lead to just another alternative:

```
valueP :: Parser Value
valueP =  integerP
      <|> floatP
      <|> charP
      <|> complexP        -- <----
      <|> many valueP
```

So have a look at parsers and parsing. And keep in mind: if you derive `Show`, you should also derive `Read`. If you feel the need to write the `Read` instance by hand, don't, instead write a parser.

Comment: This is good advice, but `deriving Show` was just for demonstration purposes; I already have a Show implementation which just delegates to the built-in versions for each type (but which I didn't want to bother including to have reviewed). I was trying to avoid rewriting the parser from scratch using a library like you describe, but maybe I'd better bite the bullet.

Comment: @pxeger I think the main point isn't really about consistency between `read` and `show`, but that `read` and `show` are really supposed to be about **one particular** type of text rendering/parsing, which is Haskell source code format. There is no such thing as "one true way" of representing values as text; there are many others (JSON, XML, nice text for end users, etc), so you write as many functions as you need. Haskell has some built-in support for **one** of these formats, which is the `Show` and `Read` classes. Using those classes but not respecting their purpose can cause difficulties.

Comment: @pxeger Your language values will have distinct representations when written down in your language's source code than when represented in Haskell code (and these might not always be 1-1 in complex cases; you might e.g. have transparently interned strings but need to treat interned strings differently from regular ones inside your implementation). Being able to easily `show` the true Haskell-level representation will help you with debugging. This should be separate from how you parse and render values from/to your language.